# RabbitMQ Stream Exception using a Dockerized Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

When starting up Spring Boot I get the following error:

> Failed to start bean
> 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry';
> nested exception is com.rabbitmq.stream.StreamException

and the cause of the error is:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: 4e31343111e9: Temporary failure in name
> resolution

The authentication passes fine for RabbitMQ - if I change the credentials then it fails at that before even reaching this stage.

Spring Boot is running using a Docker container and the RabbitMQ host is also on another host running in a container (with 5552 port open).

Answer (score 1):

The error was that there was no advertised host and port for streams in the rabbit instance - this was resolved once that was added as the explicit host IP address.